# Organisisng columns into data series in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, charts

How to organise columns so they are diferent data series in excel 2010 in a pivot chart?
Example: 
person1 month1 month2 month3 result1 result2 result 3 
person2 month1 month2 month3 result1 result2 result 3 
person3 month1 month2 month3 result1 result2 result 3

The month columns and the result columns should each be different series and have a different graph but the person column should remain as the horizontal axis as they need to be grouped by them.

so in the end you wouls have two graphs above with the data grouped by person

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following correctly, your "Axis (Category)" should be the Months column, Results as your "Values" column, and then Person as your "Legend (Series)" column.

Depending on your data, preferences, and the data your chart type will change. That said, I would at least start with Stacked-Bar.